# Generate Degeneracies in List

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have a list with n entries and I would like to duplicate this list p times.
In my case because of the Degeneracy of my Eigenvalues.
For example I have {3,2,1} and it is five-fold-degenerate so that i get
{3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1}
I did it with a loop...but in my case The Degeneracy is quite high and I hope there is a more efficient way :D

Thank you for your answers
Martin

Answer (score 1):

```
Join @@ Transpose@Table[{3, 2, 1}, {5}]
Flatten@Transpose@Table[{3, 2, 1}, {5}]
Join @@ (ConstantArray[#, 5] & /@ {3, 2, 1})
Join @@ (Table[#, {5}] & /@ {3, 2, 1})
```

all give

```
(*  {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```